# Unblock Add-In Apps in MS Office v16 for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office

I am trying to install a grammar check for MS Word (*macOS version*) which is an Add-In App.

Unfortunately, our University does not allow to install any Add-Ins as it is "blocked by administrator" (probably for security reasons, I do not know). When I asked our IT support, they were not able to help me.

Is there any "trick" to allow Add-Ins anyway, i.e., any overwrite through terminal etc. (it may be naive thinking, and I am just guessing).

Thanks.

Comment: Why? Don’t IT know the password? If not, get permision from the administrator.

Comment: @SolarMike I do not know, he just told me log out from MS Office, install the Add-In and according to him, that is it... Unfortunately, the MS Office stops to work when I log out and once I log back in, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: You install add-ins while running the app ie Word etc see the menu entry

Comment: @SolarMike This Add-In is loaded from Microsoft Store and once it opened, there is an error that my account (admin) does not allow any Add-Ins to be installed. There is no way I can change it using a "standard way" within the MS Office setting or by Privacy in macOS setting. The error is (translated to English by me): *Extension error: System administrator blocked extensions from the Office Store*.